# Runtime memory usage checker for Xcode 5 app on OS X

Tags: xcode, macos, debugging, memory, logging

Is there any way to detect and log stack/heap overflows and other types of memory usage problems, at runtime, for an app built with Xcode 5 and running on OS X, without requiring that the app be run in a debugger, and without requiring a lot of code changes?

The built-in Xcode features related to this require running in the debugger.  The Clang compiler feature AddressSanitizer is not supported by the flavor of the compiler that ships with Xcode 5.

I need to give a user a logging build to help isolate an unknown freeze issue I cannot reproduce, and it needs to be a simple as possible for them to use, as well as reasonably secure and quick for me to create.